# AR(2) simulation

Tags: time-series

I am trying to simulate 10 paths of an AR(2) system with 75 time steps in each path. It is only a system in a loose sense: the variables are connected by nothing more than the correlation in their disturbance terms.

The system has ten variables, but three should show how I am trying to run it.

```
intercepts={0.038871, 0.062392, 0.10672}
initialValues={0.0213326, 0.00916164, 0.149474}
firstLag={{0.87523, 0., 0.}, {0., -0.26885, 0.}, {0., 0., 0.087234}}
secondLag= {{-0.31856, 0., 0.}, {0., -0.12441, 0.}, {0., 0., 0.020767}}
covariance={{0.0000499966, 0.000121522, -0.0002496}, {0.000121522,
```

0.00264912, -0.00128539}, {-0.0002496, -0.00128539, 0.00416527}}

The following code returns no simulated values and no error message. Can anyone tell me what I am doing wrong?

```
RandomFunction[
   ARProcess[intercepts,{firstLag,secondLag},covariance,initialValues],{0,75},10]
```

Comment: You need to use `{initialValues}` - 1 inital point consisting of 3 values.

Comment: Thanks for taking a look at it. Solution didn't work though...

Comment: Do you get an error message ?

Comment: _italic_ **bold** `Nope'

Comment: I voted to close, but I am not sure should this question be closed as something that can be found in the documentation. From the [function page of `ARProcess`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/ARProcess.html) it is not immediately clear that the initial values for an $n$-dimensional process should be given in a matrix.

Comment: @AntonAntonov I agree to closing it, only I'd like to at least understand if my comment is relevant.

Comment: @b.gatessucks It is, because I up-voted it. :)

Answer (score 2):

Too long for a comment:

```
intercepts = {0.038871, 0.062392, 0.10672};
initialValues = {0.0213326, 0.00916164, 0.149474};
firstLag = {{0.87523, 0., 0.}, {0., -0.26885, 0.}, {0., 0., 0.087234}};
secondLag = {{-0.31856, 0., 0.}, {0., -0.12441, 0.}, {0., 0., 
    0.020767}};
covariance = {{0.0000499966, 0.000121522, -0.0002496}, {0.000121522, 
    0.00264912, -0.00128539}, {-0.0002496, -0.00128539, 0.00416527}};
paths = RandomFunction[
  ARProcess[intercepts, {firstLag, secondLag}, 
   covariance, {initialValues}], {0, 75}, 10]

ListLinePlot@
 Transpose[Thread[{#[[1]], #[[2]]}] & /@ paths["Paths"][[1]]]
```

[image: example]